# Discreteness of spectrum of operator $(p(x)y'(x))' + q(x)y(x)$ with periodic coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Suppose $p, q : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are piecewise continuous and periodic of period $a > 0$. Moreover, suppose $p$ is nowhere zero and $p'$ is piecewise continuous.

> I would like to understand the spectrum of the operator
>   $$Pf(x) = (p(x) f'(x))' + q(x) f(x),$$
>    acting on a suitable Hilbert space of functions, chosen so that the spectrum of $P$ consists precisely of countably many eigenvalues.

For instance, the following vague description, which I would like to make more precise, is given in Eastham's little book *The spectral theory of periodic differential equations* (the equation (2.1.1) that he refers to is precisely the operator $P$ I have written above).

[image]

I would like to answer the following:

1. What exactly is the Hilbert space $H$ on which we take $P$ to act? Eastham seems to suggest that we consider continuous functions equipped with $L^2$ inner product, but surely this is not a closed space?
2. What is the domain $D(P)$ of the operator $P$? Eastham seems to suggest that the domain are those functions $f$ (extended periodically to all of $\mathbb{R}$) that belong to $C^2[0,a]$ and obey $f(0)= f(a)$, $f'(0) = f'(a)$.
3. Once we have settled on an underlying Hilbert space $H$ and domain $D(P)$, how do we show that the spectrum of $P$ consists on only of countably many eigenvalues? I am not sure what techniques are crucial here, but I know that compactness, and kind of Fredholm-alternative, will be relevant. I am familiar with basic theory of unbounded operators on a Hilbert space (for instance, from Reed-Simon vol. 1) but I do not know Sturm-Liouville theory.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The domain also depends on the regularity of $q(x)$ (and I guess $p(x)$ but I'm just familiar with the case $p=1$). If it's continuous, then I believe it's just $H^2([0,a])$ with periodic boundary conditions (actually, there are a few choices or boundary conditions, $f(0)=e^{i\theta}f(a)$ and $f'(0)=e^{i\theta}f'(a)$ works). As the author alludes to, discreteness of the spectrum should follow from compactness of some sort of integral kernel for the resolvent, this is usually somewhat explicit in terms of particular solutions to the ODE. Reed Simon Volume 4 treats periodic Schrodinger operators